# Run parallel jobs on-prem dynamic spark clusters

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am new to spark, And we have a requirement to set up a dynamic spark cluster to run multiple jobs. by referring to some articles, we can achieve this by using EMR (Amazon) service.
Is there any way to the same setup that can be done locally?
Once Spark clusters are available with services running on different ports on different servers, how to point mist to new spark cluster for each job.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use a [Standalone](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html) cluster that Spark provides where you can set up Spark Cluster (master nodes and slave nodes). There are also docker containers that can be used to achieve that. Take a look [here](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-spark).

Other options it will be to take and deploy locally Hadoop ecosystems, like MapR, Hortonworks, Cloudera.

Comment: Created a Standalone spark cluster and able to run a single job without any issue.
Below are the details.
Spark version: spark-2.4.5
Mist Version: mist-1.1.1

Now our main requirement is to run multiple jobs. Could you please suggest to me how to run multiple jobs parallelly.